# how to change background image of default media player in android

Tags: android, android-intent

i have use flowing code to play audio

```
String image_url_path =  "htts: image path of url "   

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(image_url_path);

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
                        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/*"); 
                        startActivity(intent);
```

any idea then help me !